# Making existing UIViewControllers in Storyboard as master & detail

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller

I have two UIViewControllers already designed in XCode Storyboard file. All I need to do is create a UISplitViewController and make one of them master and other detail. I can't find a way to do that in Storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can make it

1. Add UISplitViewController into storyboard. You find master UINavigationController with UITableViewController as RootViewController
2. **Delete** the **root segue** between NavigationController and UITableViewController
3. Make segue From UINavigationController to your first UIViewController as **root View Controller** of UINaviagtionController
4. Then **Delete** the default detail Controller of UISplitViewController
5. Make segue from UISplitViewController to your second UIViewController
6. From RelationShip Segue's select **secondary view controller** to make  second UIViewController as **detail** view controller